# Get actual Column name from XML

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, silverlight-5.0

I have a problem with this XML.  In our system we are using XML from DataSet (`ds.GetXml()`) and send it to our Silverlight application as a string.  From there we read the XML with the following:

```
StringReader stream = new StringReader(XmlData);
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
XDocument myDoc = new XDocument();
myDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

**The problem**: Some times column names are changed, example: If a column name starts with a numeric number then it will convert it.

```
"_x0033_column" original column name was "3column"
```

Is it possible to get the original column name from the XML?

**The XML**

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <CheckboxCol>0</CheckboxCol>
    <Kunde>1</Kunde>    
    <Ort_x0020_Postfach /> 
    <erfasst_x0020_von>MasterMind</erfasst_x0020_von>   
    <Buchhaltungsnummer>1</Buchhaltungsnummer>
    <Kreditlimit>0.0000</Kreditlimit>
    <_x0033_STT_Inaktiv>Nein</_x0033_STT_Inaktiv>
    <_x0033_STT_Status>Interessent</_x0033_STT_Status>
    <Zahlungsbedingungen>10 : 10 Tage Netto</Zahlungsbedingungen>    
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <CheckboxCol>0</CheckboxCol>
    <Kunde>3</Kunde>   
    <Ort_x0020_Postfach />    
    <erfasst_x0020_von>MasterMind</erfasst_x0020_von>
    <Buchhaltungsnummer>3</Buchhaltungsnummer>
    <Kreditlimit>0.0000</Kreditlimit>
    <_x0033_STT_Inaktiv>Nein</_x0033_STT_Inaktiv>
    <_x0033_STT_Status>Kunde</_x0033_STT_Status>
    <Zahlungsbedingungen>10 : 10 Tage Netto</Zahlungsbedingungen>
  </Table>
<NewDataSet>
```

**My current Code**

```
public SLDataTable(string XmlData, Dictionary<string, string> ColumnDict)
{
    ColumnDefination = ColumnDict;

    foreach (var Item in ColumnDefination)
    {
        Columns.Add(new SLDataColumn() { ColumnName = Item.Key.ToString().Trim(), DataType = GetNullableType(GetColumnType(Item.Value.ToString())) });
    }

    StringReader stream = new StringReader(XmlData);
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);

    XDocument myDoc = new XDocument();
    myDoc = XDocument.Parse(XmlData);

    if (myDoc != null && myDoc.Elements().Count() > 0 && myDoc.Element("NewDataSet").Elements().Count() > 0)
    {
        int columnCount = myDoc.Element("NewDataSet").Element("Table").Elements().Count();
        int rowCount = myDoc.Element("NewDataSet").Elements().Count();
        string ElmentColumnName = string.Empty;

        foreach (XElement element in myDoc.Element("NewDataSet").Elements())
        {

            var row = new SLDataRow(this);

            foreach (XElement ele in element.Elements())
            {
                ElmentColumnName = ele.Name.ToString().Replace("_x0020_", " ").Replace("_x0028_", " (").Replace("_x0029_", ") ");               
                row[ElmentColumnName] = ConvertValue(ElmentColumnName, ele.Value);
            }
            Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: just use `XDocument myDoc = XDocument.Parse(XmlData);`

Comment: And what was the original name of `_x0033_STT_Status` ?

Comment: `_x0033_STT_Status` = `3STT_Status`

Comment: Is _x0033 the only conversion?  If it is, just do another Replace as you have already done for `ElmentColumnName`.

Comment: at the first start i am done by replace but the list is to much long so need some perfect solution rather then Replace.

Comment: It was only half finished and you wanted something else than Replace.

Comment: ohh - seriously say you your half solution was works for me :), if possible then please post again or your full solution